# Javascript Widget Affecting Style of the Page it is embedded in

Tags: css, widget

I'm currently developing a widget that can be embedded within a page. However, when embedded, it affects the style (font, text, layout, etc.) of the page it is embedded in.

I wonder how Clearspring and other widget frameworks encapsulate their widgets so as not to affect the embedding page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your widget, say under one div with a unique Id (or class if there will be multiple) that is least likely to clash with others on the host page. A good example might be `#company-widjet-name`. See how jQuery UI does it (`.ui-widget input`).

Then you might need to perform a sort of localised reset, to avoid the parent page's CSS from stuffing up your design. Modify something like [Eric Meyer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) to suit. Please avoid the `#uniqueId * { padding: 0, margin: 0 }` as it can cause headaches.

As long as you do

```
#uniqueId a {
    property: value;
}
```

The specificity should be strong enough to style the elements correctly without letting the host page's CSS from changing it unintentionally.

Comment: considering the fact that most of time you never know if a component/widget/block (whatever you call it) is going to be used once or more across a website I would consider the worst case scenario approach: hence use only class name.